# "Your edit must be at least X characters" is problematic at Code Golf

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, character-limit

Many times when I try to edit an answer with things like "Improved formatting" I am prohibited from doing so due to the "Your edit must be at least X characters" prompt. I understand why a rule like that exists on *most* SE sites. However on some sites like codegolf.stackexchange.com answers are, by nature, hardly any amount of characters long.

This answer, for example, is very small: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44/16513

The headline format is not within the regular formatting of the site (Code language and byte count should be bolded with the preceding #-operator.

But I can't edit the post because just making the change does not change enough characters, and I don't want to add random characters just to make the edit do-able (though that is something I see done frequently to bypass this 'rule').

Perhaps the "at least X characters" rule should have a dynamic X based on original post length. If the answer itself is only 30 characters, maybe the the 'X' should be 5; but if the answer is 200 characters then X can be 10 or whatever it is.

What do you guys think?

Comment: leave a comment so that the OP or someone whose edits don't have to be reviewed can make the change.